# When ngModel's $render is called in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

[In this official example](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#implementing-custom-form-controls_source), what is the following code doing?

```
// model -> view
ctrl.$render = function() {
  elm.html(ctrl.$viewValue);
};
```

[As far as I can see](http://plnkr.co/edit/8pN2yFwcVTVM3dReeK68?p=preview), `$render` is never called.

When `$render` is actually called?

---

**UPDATE**

Looks like `$render` is called every time the model changes. But, it is not called when the model gets its initial value. Is there a way to control the rendering of the initial value?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Right `$render` is called by Angular when a model changes. According to the [$render docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController#methods_%24render):

> $render()
>
> Called when the view needs to be updated. It is expected that the user
>   of the ng-model directive will implement this method.

It's helpful to see how `$render` is called in `ngModelWatch` (which is called whenever an `ngModel` changes).  Here we see [`$formatters`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController#properties_%24formatters) called, then the `$viewValue` updated, and finally `$render` is called:

```
$scope.$watch(function ngModelWatch() {
    var value = ngModelGet($scope);

    // if scope model value and ngModel value are out of sync
    if (ctrl.$modelValue !== value) {

      var formatters = ctrl.$formatters,
          idx = formatters.length;

      ctrl.$modelValue = value;
      while(idx--) {
        value = formatters[idx](value);
      }

      if (ctrl.$viewValue !== value) {
        ctrl.$viewValue = value;
        ctrl.$render();
      }
    }

    return value;
  });
}];
```

**The reason it's not called for the initial value** is because of this line at the end of the directive:

```
// load init value from DOM
ctrl.$setViewValue(elm.html());
```

That manually updates the view value without triggering `ngModelWatch()` and therefore without going through `$formatters` or `$render`.  If that line was instead:

```
scope.content=elm.html();
```

You'd see `$render` called by Angular as that would trigger a `$watch`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Could you explain please why in [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21084088/247243) `$render` is not called when the model changes?