# Why ngModel's $render is not called when the model changes in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/ecEqEhE/1/edit)

Why in the following example `$render` is not called when the button is clicked?

```html
<input type="text" ng-model="client.phoneNumber" phone-number>
<button ng-click="client.phoneNumber='1111111111'">Change phone number</button>
```

```javascript
.directive("phoneNumber", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$render = function() {
        alert('rendering');   // This is not called
      };
    } 
  };
});
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The `input` directive is running after your directive and thus it's `$render` function is replacing yours.

Set your directive's priority to something greater than 0.  For instance:

```
.directive("phoneNumber", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    priority: 1,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$render = function() {
        alert('rendering');
      };
    } 
  };
});
```

And your `$render` will take precedence and you'll see your alert is called.

Comment: Thanks! Makes perfect sense now.

Comment: You're welcome!  You can check out the Angular [input directive here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/cdc4d485a6daa0c74e5d07d8def2a3ee68d93d13/src/ng/directive/input.js) - it can help a lot seeing how it uses `$render`

Comment: Works, calling 'render', but the input text in losing it's value: it is becoming empty. Any idea why?

Comment: this is the actual cause https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L2250 for the same priority angular sorts by name with no warning (facepalm)

Comment: Thank you. Still unsure about Angular Directives.  Quite frustrating to program.

Comment: using priority 10 might be more reliable

Answer (score 1):

`ngModel.$render` is working, when calling `$render` in the `$apply`.

```js
app.directive('changecase', function ($timeout) {
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    priority: 1,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      
        //format text going to user (model to view)
        ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
            return value.toUpperCase();
        });

        //format text from the user (view to model)
        ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
            return value.toUpperCase();
        });

        element.on('blur keyup change', function() {
            scope.$apply(function(){
              ngModel.$setViewValue(ngModel.$modelValue);
              ngModel.$render();
            });
            });
        }
    }
});
```